# Angular 2 - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

In the file index.html i have import a file config :
    **`<script src="http://localhost:4200/src/config.js"></script>`**
The file config.js it is in the same folder as index.html but when i lunch the project it give me this error at the console: 
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to mention localhost in your src.

```
<script src="./config.js"></script>
```